# Trading strategy : Computing value of an Investment

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, finance

I am new to Python and here is my problem :

I have this DataFrame :

```
pf = pd.DataFrame({'Dates':['2018-07-31','2018-07-31','2018-08-31','2018-08-31','2018-09-30','2018-09-30'],
                   "Name":["Apple",'Faceook','JP Morgan',"Boeing",'Tesla','Disney'],
                   "Monthly Return":[-0.02,0.11,-0.03, 0.02,-0.08,0.10],
                  "Total Weight":[0.7,0.2,0.1,0.5,0.3,0.2]})
```

My objective is to return the final value of my investment according to the stocks, weight and returns for each month.

Let's say that we started with $1.000.
I'm looking for something like below, assuming that for each month the remaining capital is 
fully reinvested

```
      Dates      Name     Monthly Return    Total Weight     P&L   Remaining Investment
0   2018-07-31  Apple         -0.02            0.7           686 
1   2018-07-31  Faceook        0.11            0.3           333          1019
2   2018-08-31  JP Morgan     -0.03            0.5           494.21
3   2018-08-31  Boeing         0.02            0.5           519.69       1013.91
4   2018-09-30  Tesla         -0.08            0.1           93.28
5   2018-09-30  Disney         0.10            0.9           1003.77      1097.05
```

I started by doing this :

```
A = 1000
pf['P&L']= A * pf['Total Weight'] * (1+pf['Monthly Return'])
```

But the problem is that this is only true for the first month but not for the others as we don't 
have the same starting point ($1000 for July 31 but $1019 for August 31).

Do I have to create a loop maybe?

If you please any idea to solve this issue, please don't hesitate to share! 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For something like this it would be easier to track the returns using a zero dollar portfolio.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Dates':['2018-07-31','2018-07-31','2018-08-31','2018-08-31','2018-09-30','2018-09-30'],
                   "Name":["Apple",'Faceook','JP Morgan',"Boeing",'Tesla','Disney'],
                   "Monthly Return":[-0.02,0.11,-0.03, 0.02,-0.08,0.10],
                  "Total Weight":[0.7,0.2,0.1,0.5,0.3,0.2]})

df['weighted_return'] = df['Monthly Return'] * df['Total Weight']
rets = df.groupby(['Dates'])['weighted_return'].sum()
cumulative_rets = (rets + 1).cumprod() - 1
cumulative_rets
```

So your return series is:

```
Dates
2018-07-31   0.00800
2018-08-31   0.01506
2018-09-30   0.01100
Name: weighted_return, dtype: float64
```

Now you can consider how to incorporate transaction costs, slippage etc. The main issue with a zero dollar portfolio approach is that it assumes you can buy fractional shares. Typically this zero dollar approach is used in academic papers.

You should check out `pyfolio` for presenting results and calculating risk metrics.

Comment: @SyKer why is this the case? I get if you are comparing numbers and subtracting 'account' values in an accounting application, you would want to make sure that you have precise dollar values so account balance out as they are supposed in accounting. But how is using floating point arithmetic inaccurate for an application calculating a return series. https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html

Comment: @eNc Thank you for your help and your suggestions. I'll take look at pyfolio!

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume we have a stable monthly return. Then we need the additional integer variable `months`.

```
investment = 1000
months = 1
pf['P&L'] = investment * pf['Total Weight'] * (1+pf['Monthly Return'])**months
```